# How to programmatically add a Tab to TabControl with a ListView control docked inside it?

Tags: c#, vb.net, listview, tabs, tabcontrol

I'm using Visual Basic 9 (VS2008)

I want to create new Tabs as and when the user clicks an Add Tab button.

The Tab must have a ListView control docked inside it.

How to programmatically add a Tab to TabControl with a ListView control docked inside it?

Comment: James's answer seems to cover what you need, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will go something like this...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    // Create the listView
    Dim lstView As New ListView()
    lstView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    lstView.Items.Add("item 1") //item added for test
    lstView.Items.Add("item 2") //item added for test

    // Create the new tab page
    Dim tab As New TabPage("next tab")
    tab.Controls.Add(lstView) // Add the listview to the tab page

    // Add the tabpage to the existing TabCrontrol
    Me.TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab)

End Sub
```